# I am getting a jquery script not working error when i use a timeout function

Tags: jquery

i am using jquery in my script and in this i call a function using  setTimeout() in that function.Also i  use setTimeout() to call that function inside document.ready(function(){});

And when i run this script i getting popup error message as "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete"

i use the functions as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout( 'reloadlink()', 1000 );
    setTimeout( 'randimage()', 2000 );

});
function reloadlink(){
    $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/affliate/randomafflinks",
                    success: function(msg){
                        $('#rlinks').html(msg);
                        setTimeout( 'reloadlink()', 2000 );
                    }  
        });



}
function randimage(){
    $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/affliate/randimage",
                    success: function(msg){
                        $('#affimg').html(msg);
                        setTimeout( 'randimage()', 2000 );
                    }  
        });



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will be better if you will pass pointers to your functions instead of strings in the setTimeout. Try to call your functions like this

```
setTimeout( reloadlink, 1000 );
setTimeout( randimage, 2000 );
```

or

```
setTimeout( function(){ reloadlink(); }, 1000 );
setTimeout( function(){ randimage(); }, 2000 );
```

First variant is more preferable. Anyway when you call setTimeout with a piece of code the interpreter creates anonymous function.
Also browser stores a pointer to created timeout and will be better to store it somewhere and clear with clearTimeout. Without clearing you will waste the resources of the browser.